# css horizontal navigation menu creates unnecessary empty space

Tags: html, css

I have horizontal navigation menu with ul/li items.

I need to have 1px border around each li element. I do not need 2px border when li elements are near each other. 
This is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="top_nav">
    <li class="li_h"><a href="">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="li_au"><a href="">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="li_c"><a href="">Categories</a>
    </li>
    <li class="li_cu"><a href="">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="li_sl"><a href="">Successfull Letters</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.top_nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-image: none;
}
.top_nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}
.top_nav li {
    height: 71px;
    border-left: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
    border-top: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
}
.li_h {
    width: 89px;
}
.li_au {
    width: 99px;
}
.li_c {
    width: 110px;
}
.li_cu {
    width: 106px;
}
.li_sl {
    width: 148px;
    border-right: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
}
.top_nav li a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
.top_nav li a:hover {
    color: purple;
}
```

This code creates border as I need. However, as you see there is some space between first and second li element, second and third li element etc. I do not understand where does this space comes from and how to remove it?

You can see this in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xye3L/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to solve this problem is to set **font-size** to **0** in **.top_nav** so it will be like this

```
.top_nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-image: none;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

Also you should set **font-size** in **.top_nav li** so it will be like this

```
.top_nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 71px;
    border-left: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
    border-top: 1px solid #dfdxwxwfdf;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Maybe this link will help you, it has more details

[Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements | CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

---

Also there is another way to solve this , you can easily add **float: left** in **.top_nav li**

So it will be like this

```
.top_nav li {
    float: left;
    height: 71px;
    border-left: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
    border-top: 1px solid #dfdxwxwfdf;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
}
```

Hope this will help you ...

Answer (score 1):

Just add float: left;

```
.top_nav li {
 float: left;
 height: 71px;
 border-left: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
 border-top: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this css

```
.top_nav li {
   height: 71px;
   border-right: 1px solid #dfdfdf; 
   border-top: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
   float: left;
} 
.top_nav li:first-child {
   border-left: 1px solid #dfdfdf; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

update your css to

```
.top_nav li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xye3L/2/

Answer (score 0):

Just use `display: block` and `float: left` in your **CSS**:

```
.top_nav li {
    display: block;
    float:left;
}
```

instead of:

```
.top_nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove all spacing, tabs between all LIs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
.top_nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -3px;
}
```

This sets the distance between li element. You can adjust as necessary.